# Is there a way to run command lines asynchronously in Azure-DevOps Build Pipeline?

Tags: api, command-line, azure-devops, automated-tests, newman

I'm setting up an Azure-DevOps pipeline in which I want to include automated tests via the Newman CLI.

Imagine a pipeline like this.

```
Build Project 
Copy build to test folder  
Run the application => (API-Server) 
Run Newman 
Kill API Server Process 
On Success Copy Build to another folder.
```

My Problem is that my server application is in a waiting state after it's initialization. 
The next Task in my build pipeline won't start.

Is there a way to run multiple command lines asynchronously in Azure-DevOps?

Starting the process in via "start" won't work since it throws me an

`ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.`

```
start "%TESTDIR%\foo\bar.exe"
timeout 10
```